# Taking covariance is Lipschitz

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, lipschitz-functions

Suppose $\mu, \nu$ are probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^p$. Let $X,Y$ be i.i.d. samples of size $m$ drawn from $\mu,\nu$. Does there exist a constant $C > 0$ that depends only on the numbers $p$ and $m$, such that the following holds?
$$\|\Sigma_X-\Sigma_Y\|_2 < C \cdot W_p(\mu,\nu)$$
Here, $\Sigma_X$ is the covariance matrix of the random variable , $\|A\|_2$ is the 2-norm of a matrix $A$, and $W_p (\mu, \nu)$ is the $p$-Wasserstein distance between $\mu$ and $\nu$.

If there is a weaker result, or a similar result with the Wasserstein distance replaced by something else, I'd love to know them as well.

---

**Update:** I proved this own my own, assuming that $X,Y$ are compactly supported. But the proof is a little long. I would be glad to know about an existing reference to this.

Comment: I would suggest to change the title in "Covariance matrix is Lipschitz"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Prop 3.3 in page 14 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.06357.pdf). We have:
$$\|\Sigma_X-\Sigma_Y\|_2 < 8r \cdot W_p(\mu,\nu)$$
where the each measure is supported on some radius-$r$ ball.